# Springboot/Spring JPA - Controller with multiple GetMapping methods

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation where I have several SQL queries getting data from same table, just filtering differently.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE CAR_NUM <> 111    

SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE SELL_DATE BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-15'  //These are DB2 TIMESTAMP fields (e.g. '2021-12-15 12:45:33')
    
SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE ...

...
```

...

I have about 10 queries, each against `CAR` data table but with different `WHERE` clause filtering data in a different way.

I implemented `CarController`, `CarService`, `CarRepository` using Spring JPA.  My Controller currently has 2 `@GetMapping` methods and I am planning to add more `@GetMapping` methods to cover all SQL queries I have above

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars") 
public class CarController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<CarResponse> getAllCars() {
      // handle 1st query above and return all cars except one with CAR_NUM=111
      List<CarResponse> cars = carRepository.getAllCarsExceptTrippleOne();
      return cars;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<CarResponse> getAllCarsSoldBetweenDates(@RequestParam Map<Date, Date> dateRange) {
      // handle 2nd query above and return all cars sold btw 2 dates.  My table holds DB2 TIMESTAMP fields.
      List<CarResponse> cars = carRepository.getAllCarsSoldBetweenDates(dateRange.get("startDate"), dateRange.get("endDate"));
      return cars;
    }

}
```

However, I get error like:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map
> 'carController' method
> com.me.carController#getAllCarsSoldBetweenDates(Map) to {GET [/cars],
> produces [application/json]}: There is already 'carController' bean
> method com.me.carController#getAllCars() mapped.

I am not sure what is that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell spring which `GET` mapping to invoke when you want to get all cars and which one to use when you want to get cars sold between dates.

Leave the first one alone and change your second method to something like this:

```java
  @GetMapping("/sold/{startDate}/{endDate}")
  public List<CarResponse> getAllCarsSoldBetweenDates(@PathVariable Long startDate, @PathVariable Long endDate) {
      // do validation of the variables, if variables cannot be converted to dates or something
      try{
          Date startDateObj = new Date(startDate);   
          Date endDateObj = new Date(endDate);

          // handle 2nd query above and return all cars sold btw 2 dates
          List<CarResponse> cars = carRepository.getAllCarsSoldBetweenDates(startDateObj, endDateObj);
          return cars;
      }catch( Exception e ){
          // .. handle exception and return empty list?
          return Collections.emptyList();
      }      
  }
```

Then, to call this method, you invoke by calling your server and passing the params, like:

`https://<server>:<port>/cars/sold/<startDateAsLong>/<endDateAsLong>`

Comment: Thank you, that is great.  I fogot to mention that my table dates are DB2 Timestamps.  Will this still work?

Comment: In that case, use the `DBTimestamp(long time)` constructor instead of `Date(long time)` to create your objects.  For example `DBTimestamp startDateObj = new DBTimestamp(startDate);`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to pass Date selected in a date picker component, so it is not Long as you are passing it.  User will select date in date picker component on website like 2021-10-12 and pass that to the controller. Why are you using Long?  Why not Date or Timestamp?  And why is URL taking Long representation of Date rather than selected date itselt like:  `https://<server>:<port>/cars/sold/2020-01-02/2021-10-12` Thanks

Comment: A date is usually the number of milliseconds since epoch (hence, why the `Long` parameter).  What you are seeing is the String formatted representation of it and you can certainly pass that instead - it just means you need to parse it and convert it into a date on your method.  I find this being more work since it means you need to parse the string into a date first, just like the Long.  However, the string may come in different formats or not parseable into a date at all so this makes it more error prone.  The date selected in the datepicker can always be converted into a Long and pass that

Comment: No problem! - glad I could help

Comment: Any idea why I am not getting correct results?  For example, I know I should get 2 records between 2021-09-01 and 2021-10-01 and that is what I get in DB2 console when I issue `SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.CAR WHERE SELL_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2021-09-01 23:59:59' AND '2021-10-01 23:59:59';`.  However, the controller returns nothing but I know code is correct because if I increase date range, I eventually start getting data.  So it seems like the dates passed in are somehow mishandled?

Comment: @pixel  what are the dates on those records?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.... You mean the dates I get back in DB2 console for the above SQL SELECT query?  I just get the 2 dates that fall btw the above range.

Comment: Yes, what are the dates of the records when you use the SELECT query?

Comment: an example would be `2021-09-29 16:06:35`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the log? you might have to debug the program to see where the error is happening...

Comment: Could it be the fact that my Entity uses `java.sql.Timestamp` and I use that since my DB2 field is a DB2 `TIMESTAMP` but the controller is sending `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realized my error and deleted my comment

Comment: Yes, the difference between the dates can make a difference... they all should be using the same `Date` object

Comment: Yes!!!  That was it.  Thank you

Comment: @pixel nice! glad it worked out

Answer (score 2):

You specified `@GetMapping()` to both of your methods. This binds both methods with one endpoint `/cars`. Each controller method should have unique mapping associated with it.

```
@GetMapping
public List<CarResponse> getAllCars() {}

@GetMapping("/soldbetween")
public List<CarResponse> getAllCarsSoldBetweenDates(@RequestParam Map<Date, Date> dateRange) {}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would the actual URL look like in Postman?

Comment: ````/cars/```` for getAllCars() ````/cars/soldbetween```` along with request parameters map containing start and end date with request parameter name ````dateRange```` for getAllCarsSoldBetween()

Comment: Thanks but how would that Uri look like?  Could you give me an example.  Thanks again